# update momentjs object with other momentjs object

Tags: fullcalendar, momentjs

How to update momentjs object with other momentjs object without changing reference?

```
var aObj = moment();
var bObj = moment();
```

I would like to update all members of `aObj` with `bObj` members.

Answer (score 0):

This code is doing what you want

```
var bObj = moment();
var aObj = moment(bObj);
```

Comment: I would like to update object, not create new with others content.

Answer (score 0):

This code mutates the moment-object, but doesn´t take care about the timezone:

```
var momentA = moment().tz("Europe/Berlin");
var momentB = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").add(2, 'years');
momentA.set(momentB.toObject());
console.log(momentA.tz()); // "Europe/Berlin"
console.log(momentA.format()); // 2019-02-07T14:11:36+01:00
```

edit:
You could also use Object.assign()

```
Object.assign(momentA, momentB.clone());
console.log(momentA.tz()); // "America/Los_Angeles"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

var bObj = moment();
var aObj = bObj.clone();

Then you can check with bObj.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:ss") and aObj.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:ss").